# why my joomla controllers method is not getting executed

Tags: model-view-controller, joomla, components

I have an ajax method which sends data to one of my controller but the method inside of my controller is not getting fired. Everytime the first method is getting executed on call. The controller looks as it follows

```
class TieraerzteControllerUploader extends JController
{
        /**
         * display task
         *
         * @return void
         */

            function display($cachable = false) 
        {
              require_once JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR.'/helpers/upload.php';

              $upload_handler = new UploadHandler();
              //this one is going to be outputed
              die();
        }


          public function locator(){
           // I wait here for a dump, but is not happening
           var_dump('test');
           die();
           echo '{"text":"John Smith","id":"433"},{"text":"Paul Sparks","id":"434"}';

        }

}
```

I call the controller with the following url

```
/administrator/index.php?option=com_tieraerzte&task=uploader.locator&tmpl=component&q=search
```

even if I call the above url the result is the same

Comment: Everything looks right from a code perspective as to how it should look. There could be many reasons why this isn't working though. A little more info would help me get you a good answer. 1) What version of Joomla! is this? 2) Can you post your tieraerzte.php and your controller.php as well?

Comment: can you provide the link that works? is the uploader controller in ./controllers folder?

Comment: thank you for your feedback in the mean time I found the error.

Comment: How about posting the answer?

Comment: Sorry guys was my mistake, being tired I swaped some files. The posted function is working good.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using wrong formated joomla url.
Try this url formate,u may call the controller

**index.php?option=com_tieraerzte&view=uploader&tmpl=component&q=search**

watch the difference between your url and my url.